# How to stop "[object Object]" from printing rather than the object itself?

Tags: javascript, html

my problem probably has an incredibly easy fix, but I'm new to javascript and can't seem to find an answer for it. Heres the script:

```
var proxyUrl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/',
    targetUrl = 'https://api.darksky.net/forecast/[key]/[latitude],[longitude]'
fetch(proxyUrl + targetUrl)
  .then(blob => blob.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    document.getElementById('weather').innerHTML = data;
  })
```

However when i run it, the `<p>` element doesnt change to the data itslef, it changes to "[object Object]" What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

PS: the `targetUrl` variable has placeholders where the parameters go, it won't run as-is.

Comment: `data` is not a string, it is an object. Your `console.log(data)` will show you the contents of the object. If there's a specific property of the object you want to display, use `data.PropertyName`.

Comment: If you want to print the whole object just use: `JSON.stringify(data);`

Comment: Is "weather" I'd of the <p> element?

Comment: Setting the innerHTML value will call `toObject` which will print `[object Object]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I understand you are trying to print the data into `<p>` element with id as "weather".

Please replace following line.

```
document.getElementById('weather').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
```

It will work just fine.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/957537/5037905) may help if you're looking for different ways to inspect your object.

Answer (score 1):

Check the data returned by the API call and then add it to the html. I think it is returning an object and you are trying to display that object in the DOM.