# Javascript object printing as object object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am very new to both node and mongo db.I was creating a connection from node to Mongo and trying the CRUD Operations.My operations are defined in operations.js and i am calling the functions from index.

The issue i am facing is when i am printing  the callback parameter from

`coll.find({}).toarray()` - that is result i am getting the desired output as

```
[
  {
    _id: 5ea4843b0f28320524d23f14,
    name: 'Vadonut',
    description: 'Test Vadonut'
  },
]
```

but when i am printing the result from index.js which is a result of the callback from the functions in operation.js i am getting the output as

```
[object Object]
```

Can i get help on this?????

**index.js :**

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');
const dboper = require('./operations')
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
const dbname = "dishes";

MongoClient.connect(url,(err,client)=>{
    assert.equal(err,null);

    console.log("Connected correctly correct to the server");

    const db =client.db(dbname);


    dboper.insertdocument(db,{"name":"Vadonut","description":"Test Vadonut"},'dishes',(result)=>{
        console.log('Insert Document:\n'+result);

        dboper.finddocument(db,'dishes',(result)=>{
           console.log("Found Documents :\n"+result);
    })

})
```

****operations.js****

```
const assert = require('assert');

exports.insertdocument = (db,document,collection,callback)=>{
    const coll = db.collection(collection);
    coll.insertOne(document,(err,result)=>{
        assert.equal(err,null);
        console.log("Inserted " + result.result.n + "documents inserted into the collection"+collection);
        console.log(result.ops);
        callback(result);

    })

};

exports.finddocument = (db,collection,callback)=>{
    const coll = db.collection(collection);
    coll.find({}).toArray((err,docs)=>{
        assert.equal(err,null);
        console.log(docs);
        callback(docs);
    })
};
```

Comment: Did you try JSON.stringify on your result object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[object Object]` is the default/automatic string conversion for an object.

So, if you use an object anywhere in a string manipulation expression such as this:

```
let x = {greeting: "hello"};
let str = "I would like to say the greeting " + x;
console.log(str);
```

Then, the JS interpreter will try to convert your object `x` to a string and that default string conversion will be `[object Object]` so you will get a result of:

```
 I would like to say the greeting [object Object]
```

What you need to do is either avoid using a Javascript object anywhere in a string expression or explicitly convert the object to JSON with `JSON.stringify()` before involving it in a string expression.

I would replace this:

```
console.log("Inserted " + result.result.n + "documents inserted into the collection"+collection);
```

with this:

```
console.log("Inserted ",  result.result.n, "documents inserted into the collection", collection);
```

Then, you're passing whole objects to `console.log()` and it will do its normal object display on them rather than let JS try to auto-convert them to a string.

You could also manually convert those objects to string form with `JSON.stringify(result.result.n)` and then use them in string expressions.

Answer (score 2):

It is because of two different behavior of console log with "," and "+".

```js
let user = {"_id":"5ea4843b0f28320524d23f14", "name":"Vadonut"};
  
console.log("doc"+ user)

console.log("doc", user)
```

Also the check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957537/how-can-i-display-a-javascript-object)

Comment: @Nayan..yes that was the reason..ty for the help

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with JSON.stringify(result)

like this

```
dboper.insertdocument(db,{"name":"Vadonut","description":"Test Vadonut"},'dishes',(result)=>{
        console.log('Insert Document:\n'+JSON.stringify(result));

        dboper.finddocument(db,'dishes',(result)=>{
           console.log("Found Documents :\n"+JSON.stringify(result));
    })
```

Comment: @Abhishek..Yes it helps..thanks..but i am not able to understand why this is happening.Even when i am getting the result object in operations.js then i am able to print that Json object.

Comment: had the code been `console.log(result)`, you would have seen the data. if you concatenate with a string, then you need to use JSON.stringify. Or, as @nayan mentioned in the other answer, you can do like `console.log("Found Documents: \n", result)`