# both formating and seeing contents of an object in typescript

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to print out both user and company objects when i use **console.log(user,company)** it all working fine and i can see the objects content but the outformat is not desired . i tried to template it with backticks but in that case i just get an output like **[object, object]** is there a way to both format and see inside object at the same time ? 
User and Company are two classes that made objects with same names respectively and 
the code below is what im trying to achieve .

```
import { User } from "./User";
import { Company } from "./Company";
const user = new User();
const company = new Company();
console.log(`
${user}
${comapny}
`);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I display a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957537/how-can-i-display-a-javascript-object)

Comment: @palaѕн not pretty much ... i mean the question was asked like 10years ago .. es6 has not been introduced yet and its using object directly without backtick ... i was seeking for a solution via backtick to get off that manual formatings

Answer (score 0):

You should give a try to:

```js
JSON.stringify(user, null, 2)
JSON.stringify(company, null, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement method `toString()` in your `User` and `Company` classes.