# How to print the object value which return type is [Object , Object] in Nod JS?

Tags: node.js, webdriver-io

below is one piece of code where i have to compare one object stored value (i.e 'resort') with the value  compare that value what i am getting from the JSON file .

code -

```
resort = _.find(this.resorts.entries, (o) => {
      return o.gqe_name === resort;  
    })
```

;

i have tried to get the value but the it is displaying as [Object,Object ] , tried with `console .log('resort'+ resort)` and `log.info ('resort'+ resort).`

is there any way i can view the return value ?

how i can print json stored value `'o.gqe_name'` ?

Comment: did you try `console.log('resort', resort)` if that doesnt work `console.log('resort', JSON.stringify(resort))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I display a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957537/how-can-i-display-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Yes  Schnecke, it is displaying as 
resort :-[object Object]

Answer (score 1):

JSON.stringify can help

```js
const object = { test: { test2: 'value' } }
const result = JSON.stringify(object)
const result2 = JSON.stringify(object, null, 2)
console.log(result)
console.log(result2)
```

Comment: i have tried writing in this way but getting error .. 

const result = JSON.stringify(gqe_name)
    /console.log ('result' +result)

Error -
ReferenceError: gqe_name is not defined

Comment: Aleksandr Smyshliaev can you assist me please , How i can write in proper way to get the O/p

Comment: resort = _.find(this.resorts.entries, (o) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(o.gqe_name, null, 2));
      return o.gqe_name === resort;  
    })