# How to know the object value in Java Script

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver-io

HI can i able to print the 'bookingPreferences' value in the console ?

```
let bookingPreferences = {
      destination: hotel.ancestorDestination.name.toLowerCase (),
      destinationId: hotel.ancestorDestination.shortId,
      checkInDate: new moment ().add (dateCount, (dateScale.includes ('month') ? 'months' : 'days')).format ('YYYY-MM-DD'),
      checkOutDate: new moment ().add (dateCount, (dateScale.includes ('month') ? 'months' : 'days')).add (6, 'days').format ('YYYY-MM-DD'),

      partyMix: {
        adultCount: 1,
        childCount: 0,
        nonAdultAges: []
      },
      resortId: hotel.id
    };
```

i have tried with `var value= JSON.stringify ('bookingPreferences' + bookingPreferences);`

which was not helpful . kindly let me know what is the way to know the value nested object value ?

Comment: What do you mean by **'bookingPreferences' value**? Can you be more specific? You can easily print an object in the console by  `console.log(bookingPreferences)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I display a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957537/how-can-i-display-a-javascript-object)

Comment: bookingPreferences is a variable which value i want to print

Comment: `console.log(bookingPreferences)`

Comment: Then go with `console.log(bookingPreferences)` Is there a problem with that? If so it may relate to other issues like where on your code you are trying to print. Maybe before the object is declared, or a possible AJAX issue.

Comment: i have tried with console.log(bookingPreferences) which is displaying me as [Object, Object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the hotel object you are passing into your bookingPreferences. Then a simple console.log(bookingPreferences) will do the trick for you.