# how to get nested object value inside a function in javascript while object destructuring?

Tags: javascript, object, object-destruction

while practicing object destructuring ; I faced some problems.

I have a object like this:

```
const secondObject = {
    value : 2,
    credit: 23, 
    details: {
        serialNumber : 4
    }
}
```

Now I want to get 'serialNumber' value inside a function parameter. so I invoke a function like this :

```
function output({value, details}){
    console.log(`value: ${value} , detail: ${details}`);
}
output(secondObject);
```

when I log it into console the result showing : **detail: [object Object]**

*but if I do like this ,I got the serialNumber's value : *

```
 const {details: {serialNumber}} =  secondObject;
console.log(serialNumber);
```

can anyone tell me how can I get the value inside a function?

Comment: You can use the same idea you used for your variable but in your argument: `{value, details: {serialNumber}}`

Comment: You may want to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get a specific attribute inside `details`, then you can directly access it:

```
function output({value, details}){
    console.log(`value: ${value} , detail: ${details.serialNumber}`);
}
```

or equivalently, as suggested by [Nick Parsons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5648954/nick-parsons) in the comments:

```
function output({value, details: {serialNumber}}){
    console.log(`value: ${value} , detail: ${serialNumber}`);
}
```

If instead you want to show the full object contained in `details`, then you can use `JSON.stringify`, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4293047/9948255). Have a look at this piece of code.

```
const secondObject = {
    value : 2,
    credit: 23, 
    details: {
        serialNumber : 4,
        fooBar: 42
    }
}

function output({value, details}){
    str = JSON.stringify(details);
    console.log(`value: ${value} , detail: ${str}`);
}

output(secondObject);
// value: 2 , detail: {"serialNumber":4,"fooBar":42}
```